# error 9 subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to populate a dynamic array with data from a sheet. I get the "error 9 subscript out of range". Why?

```
Sub correct()

Dim row As Integer, i As Long
Dim constants() As Double 'this declares the dynamic array
row = 1
i = 0

ReDim constans(0) 'this resizes the array(rediminsion's the array)

Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Deg 4").Cells(row, 1).Value = ""
    constants(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Deg 4").Cells(row, 1).Value
    i = i + 1 'increments array index
    ReDim Preserve constants(i) 'resize the array 1 larger and preserves previous data
    row = row + 1 'increments the worksheet row
Loop 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled your array's name:

```
ReDim constans(0)
```

Should be:

```
ReDim constants(0)
```

So, by mistake, you're using `ReDim` to declare a new array called `constans`, and `constants` remains unallocated. When you get to the `constants(i) = ...` line in your procedure, you get that error because `constants` is unallocated.

I had never come across this particular screw-up before; I'm actually appalled that the VBA language is set up to allow this! [Microsoft does warn against this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266231%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) (**emphasis** mine):

> *Caution*: The `ReDim` statement acts as a declarative statement if the variable it declares doesn't exist at module level or procedure
>   level. If another variable with the same name is created later, even
>   in a wider scope, `ReDim` will refer to the later variable and won't
>   necessarily cause a compilation error, **even if `Option Explicit` is
>   in effect**. To avoid such conflicts, `ReDim` should not be used as a
>   declarative statement, but simply for redimensioning arrays.

Ok, thanks for the well-hidden warning, but they should just not have given `ReDim` declarative functionality in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the declarative ReDim. It hasn't caught me before but fore-warned is fore-armed. I won't be fooled by it in future!

Comment: Thanks this really helped, also thanks for the warning about ReDim. Im only using ReDim because its the only way that I know how to create a dynamic array. Is the a better way to do this with out using ReDim?

Comment: No. That's the way to use it -- as long as you spell the array name correctly!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your declarations

```
Dim constants() As Double 'this declares the dynamic array
```

but you `ReDim` a different undeclared array

```
ReDim constans(0) 'this resizes the array(rediminsion's the array)
```

Adding the missing "t" to "constans" will fix that.  If you want to avoid inadvertently using undeclared variables then go to Tools..> Options..>Editor tab and make sure the **"Require Variable Declaration** is checked - this will insert `Option Explicit` at the top of every module you create (but not your existing ones).

With `Option Explicit` and CamelCase variables declared, as you enter your variable names in lower case (i.e. `camelcase`) the next time you press *Enter*, they will change to `CamelCase` as declared confirming that the name entered has been declared. If it doesn't change then it's undeclared and it will cause a compile error when you try to run the procedure.

**Before** you **run** your procedure, **compile it** by going to **Debug..> Compile VBA Project** or press *Alt > d > l*. If you don't see a message box, then it will probably run

**PS:** You may get unexpected results with your current loop because my testing showed constants(0) = 1 and so on until constants(last i) = 0. Probably not what you want but if it is, then...all good!

Comment: `Option Explicit` won't help in this case. Error won't show at compile time because `constans` is *not* undeclared; it's declared by `ReDim`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19764824/119775), which you might have wanted to read before posting yours. Good point regarding the camelCase trick, though; I would also suggest using autocomplete (Ctrl-space) to prevent typos.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I was slowly typing while you beat me to the answer. I did notice before posting that another answer had been posted but was a bit scared that looking at it may have wiped out all my work.